# CASE statement math does not always make sense

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL statement which does some math. It calculates base points, bonus points, and total points (base + bonus = total).

Most of the time (99%) the calculation is as expected. But sometimes the total returned is not base + bonus. I can't figure out why that would be.

Here's the relevant SQL

```
   SUM(CASE
        WHEN validated = 1 AND invalidated = 0
        THEN ptsBase
        ELSE 0
        END) AS awardedPoints,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN validated = 1 AND invalidated = 0
        THEN ptsBonus
        ELSE 0
        END) AS awardedBonus,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN validated = 1 AND invalidated = 0
        THEN ptsBase + ptsBonus
        ELSE 0
        END) AS awardedTotal,
```

> Note: The calculations for awardedPoints AND awardedBonus is always accurate. As far as I can tell, the awardedTotal calculation is the only one that's off.

In the case I'm looking at right now

- awardedPoints = 1345
- awardedBonus = 46
- awardedTotal = 1377 (expect it be 1391, 14 points off)

Comment: `ptsBase + ptsBonus` will be null if either of the inputs are null.

Comment: try by using COALESCE

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Martin Smith, McNets, and CBroe. You all nailed it. I was just about to post that the bonus points column is null sometimes. Changing the code to below worked...

```
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN validated = 1 AND invalidated = 0
        THEN ptsBase
        ELSE 0
        END) AS awardedPoints,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN validated = 1 AND invalidated = 0
        THEN ptsBonus
        ELSE 0
        END) AS awardedBonus,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN validated = 1 AND invalidated = 0
        THEN ptsBase + COALESCE(ptsBonus, 0)
        ELSE 0
        END) AS awardedTotal,
```

Comment: You should probably coalesce the other ones as well in case they are null as well

Comment: Thanks, I actually just cleaned up the data and will enforce NON NULL. They shouldn't be NULL to begin with.